# Express post body not changing/ updating values

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working on a small node.js project that takes the input of a html page and inserts the values into google sheets. Once I run the program, I can post the values to the sheet easily enough. However, when I try to do this again without restarting the program, the values do not update. I tried `console.log(req.body);`from within the `app.post`function and the values are the same, requiring me to restart the program to insert a new series of values. When I call the value of the request from within the posting function, it displays the correct values, but the changes does not appear in the sheet. Additionally, no error messages appear.

Has anyone else encountered this bug? What can be done to alleviate it?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Sheets updating code (active is a array of arrays containing the data where the x axis is each individual unit)

```
for (var i=0; i<active.length; i++){
        var request1 = {
            spreadsheetId:  <id>,
            range:  active[i][4].toUpperCase() + active[i][5] ,
            auth: auth,
            valueInputOption: "RAW",
            resource: {
                "range": active[i][4].toUpperCase() + active[i][5],
                "values": [[active[i][1]]]
            }
        }
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request1, function(err, response){
            if (err) return err;
        });
}
```

I recognize that `update` can take multiple arguments, but I found it easier to just issue multiple requests. I don't think that this is causing the issue because updates only containing one unit are still affected.

Comment: would you be able to post some code so we get an idea of how you're updating the google sheets?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow updated

Comment: In my environment, I cannot reproduce your situation. Can I ask you about the flow for reproducing your situation?

Comment: Sure, I'm calling this post from within several google sheets get requests which allow me to locate where I need to make the post. The post instructions for express are outside these async functions. I'm additionally making using two different post commands to post to separate spreadsheets

Comment: If the script you show has the issue, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your situation in my environment. I'm sorry. So how about trying to the several requests for spreadsheet by one call?

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks for the help